# How can I add items into a struct without creating variables

Tags: c, struct

I am using a struct to store a string and an integer like so:

```
struct movement {
    char *direction;
    int steps;
};
```

I can add items into the struct by doing this

```
struct movement m1= { "right",20 };
struct movement m2= { "left" ,10 };
```

The end result I am trying to achieve is to collect user inputs (e.g. "right 20"), and store it in the struct. How can I store an unknown number of user inputs into the struct without the use of variables (m1, m2 etc) since I will not know how many items there will be at the end.

Comment: A [linked list](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/c-linked-list-example/) can help

Comment: Be warned that above you do *not* "add items into the struct" in any way. You are creating two separate struct instances, which do not have to do anything with each other.

Comment: An array of structures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a linked list. It is a recursive data structure which would be great for what you want.

Here is some example code I wrote a while ago that might help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* basic linked list structure */
typedef struct node node_t;

struct node {
    char *direction;
    int steps;
    node_t *next;
};

/* pointers to the head and tail of the list */
typedef struct {
    node_t *head;
    node_t *foot;
} list_t;

list_t *initialize_list(void);
list_t *insert_nodes(list_t *list, char *direction, int steps);
void free_list(list_t *list);
node_t *generate_node(void);
void print_list(list_t *list);
void exit_if_null(void *ptr, const char *msg);

int
main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    list_t *list;

    /* empty list created */
    list = initialize_list();

    /* inserting information one a time */
    list = insert_nodes(list, "right", 20);
    list = insert_nodes(list, "left", 10);

    print_list(list);

    /* freeing list at the end */
    free_list(list);
    list = NULL;

    return 0;
}

/* function to insert information into a node */
list_t
*insert_nodes(list_t *list, char *direction, int steps) {

    /* called generate_node() to create a new node */
    node_t *new;
    new = generate_node();

    /* puts steps information into node */
    new->steps = steps;

    /* allocates space for direction string */
    /* this is needed because *direction is a pointer */
    new->direction = malloc(strlen(direction)+1);

    /* copies direction info into node */
    strcpy(new->direction, direction);

    /* inserting information at the tail of the list */
    new->next = NULL;

    if (list->foot == NULL) {
        /* first insertion into list */
        list->head = list->foot = new;
    } else {
        list->foot->next = new;
        list->foot = new;
    }

    /* returns modified list */
    return list;
}

.* function which generates new nodes */
node_t
*generate_node(void) {
    node_t *newnode;

    /* create space for new node */
    newnode = malloc(sizeof(*newnode));
    exit_if_null(newnode, "Allocation");

    /* initialize node info to nothing */
    newnode->direction = NULL;
    newnode->steps = 0;

    return newnode;
}

/* creates the empty linked list */
list_t 
*initialize_list(void) {
    list_t *list;

    create space for list */
    list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    exit_if_null(list, "Allocation");

    /* set pointers to NULL */
    /* We don't want them pointing at anything yet */
    list->head = list->foot = NULL;

    return list;
}

/* function which prints entire list */
void
print_list(list_t *list) {

    /* start at the head of the list */
    node_t *curr = list->head;

    while (curr) {
        printf("%s %d\n", curr->direction, curr->steps);

        /* steps through the list */
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

/* function which frees nodes */
void
free_list(list_t *list) {
    node_t *curr, *prev;

    /* start at beginning of list */
    curr = list->head;

    /* frees nodes one at a time */
    while(curr) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        free(prev);
    }

    /* frees entire list */
    free(list);
}

/* function which checks malloc(), and whether enough space was allocated */
void
exit_if_null(void *ptr, const char *msg) {
    if (!ptr) {
        printf("Unexpected null pointer: %s\n", msg);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ryan Chia, did this code somewhat help? I can explain it in more detail if you want.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm quite new to C, so explanations would be help greatly :)

Comment: Yeah no problem @RyanChia. I will add comments to the code, and I also suggest looking into them on the internet. They are a very useful data structure when wanting to thread structure object information together.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't sound as if you really want to "store values into the struct", instead you want to store a sequence of independent struct instances; one for each user input.

The three most basic ways of doing this are:

- An array, whose size you select at compile-time. It shouldn't be too hard to make it "large enough" for reasonable input
- An array whose size you set (and then *grow*) at run-time
- A linked list of structure instances

Which one to prefer depends on which you think is simplest. If at all possible, a static appeoach is always simplest. You can easily have something like

```
struct movement movements[10000];
```

at the global level, this will only cost perhaps 120 KB on a 64-bit system. Note though that this doesn't include memory for the `direction` strings; if those are always chosen from "right" and "left" (and perhaps "up"/"down" too) you could represent it as an enum instead:

```
enum direction { DIRECTION_LEFT = 0, DIRECTION_RIGHT, DIRECTION_UP, DIRECTION_DOWN };
```

This will make the structure "self-contained" and (on 64-bit systems) smaller since the enumeration will be smaller than a pointer.

Dynamically growing an array using `realloc()` isn't too hard, you could look that up easily as its often used.

Comment: I ending up using an entirely different approach and not using struct to accomplish what I wanted to achieve. However, I am still interested in trying out a linked list for this. I tried looking around online, but only found "linked list using structures" rather than "linked list of structures". I tried tweaking things around trying to get them to work with structures but had no progress in doing so. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @RyanChia That sounds like pretty much the same thing; linked lists in C are almost always implemented using structures, it's the natural way to do it. The things that get stored in each element can be either pointers (to whatever you want) or structures defined by the application.

Answer (score -1):

Use a LinkedList to store an indefinite number of movements.
For each movement, create a node in the linked list and update the next pointer.

```
struct node {
  struct movement m;
  node* next;
}
```